# hive agg asking for column in group by

Tags: hadoop, group-by, hive, case

I have a basic query(rewritten with vague names), I do not understand why hive is asking for the `t2.description` column in the case statement to be added to the group by.  I appeased them and put it in but of course I get null value for that column for every row...  If i take out the case statement and query the raw data I get all the lovely descriptions.  only when I want to add some logic with the case statement does it fail.  I am new to Hive and understand it is not ANSI sql but I did not imagine it to be this finicky.

```
select
t1.columnid               as column_id,
(case when t2.description in ('description1','description2','description3') then t2.description else null end) as label_description

from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on (t1.inresult = t2.inresult)

group by
t1.columnid
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often difficult to understand the actual problem based on the error logs shown by Hive's sql parser. The problem here is that you are selecting 2 columns but only applying the GROUP BY to one column. To make this query executable you must do one of the following:

1. Group by both column 1 and column 2

> select t1.columnid as column_id,
>       (case when t2.description in ('description1','description2','description3') then t2.description
>   else null end) as label_description from table1 t1 left outer join
>   table2 t2 on (t1.inresult = t2.inresult) GROUP BY t1.columnid, (case
>   when t2.description in ('description1','description2','description3')
>   then t2.description else null end);

2. Do not use a GROUP BY statement

> select t1.columnid as column_id,
>       (case when t2.description in ('description1','description2','description3') then t2.description
>   else null end) as label_description from table1 t1 left outer join
>   table2 t2 on (t1.inresult = t2.inresult)

3. Apply an aggregate function to column 2

> select t1.columnid as column_id,
>       MIN(case when t2.description in ('description1','description2','description3') then t2.description
>   else null end) as label_description from table1 t1 left outer join
>   table2 t2 on (t1.inresult = t2.inresult) group by t1.columnid

For hive, if you are using a GROUP BY then all the columns you are selecting must either be in the GROUP BY statement or be wrapped in an aggregate statement applied such as MAX, MIN or SUM.

Comment: 1. gives null for `label_description` for every row; 2. Does not run asks for a group by; 3. put `case when min(t2.description)` still asks for `t2.description` in group by and we cannot put `min()` around `t1.columnid` as I want every entry not just the `min()`... You essentially just stated every work around for an RDBMS and have not shed any light on Hive other than the parser logs are difficult to understand, which I clearly know as I'm here posting this question...